# Join multiple Kafka topics by key

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How can write a consumer that joins multiple Kafka topics in a scalable way?

I have a topic that published events with a key and a second topic that publishes other events related to a subset of the first with the same key. I would like to write a consumer that subscribes to both topics and performs some additional actions for the subset that appears in both topics.

I can do this easily with a single consumer: read everything from both topics, maintaining state locally and perform the actions when both events have been read for a given key. But I need the solution to scale.

Ideally I need to tie the topics together so that they are partitioned the same way and the partitions are assigned to consumers in sync. How can i do this?

I know Kafka Streams joins topics together such that keys are allocated to the same nodes. How do they do it? P.S. I can't used Kafka Streams because I'm using Python.

Comment: Spark streaming is a viable option as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too bad you are on Python -- Kafka Streams would be a perfect fit :)

If you want to do this manually, you will need to implement your own `PartitionAssignor` -- this, implementation must ensure, that partitions are co-located in the assignment: Assume you have 4 partitions per topic (let's call them A and B), than partitions A_0 and B_0 must be assigned to the same consumer (also A_1 and B_1, ...).

I hope Python consumer allows you to specify a custom partition assignor via config parameter `partition.assignment.strategy`.

This is the `PartitionAssignor` Kafka Streams uses: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamPartitionAssignor.java

Streams uses the concept of tasks -- a tasks gets partitions of different topics with the same partition number assigned. Streams also tries to do a "sticky assignment" -- ie., don't move task (and thus partitions) in case of rebalance if possible. Thus, each consumer encodes its "old assignment" in the rebalance metadata.

Basically, the method `#subscription()` is called on each consumer that is alive. It will send the subscription information of the consumer (ie, to what topics a consumer wants to subscribe) plus optional metadata to the brokers.

In a second step, the leader of the consumer group, will compute the actual assignment, within `#assign()`. The responsible broker collects all information given by `#subscription()` in the first phase of the rebalance and hands it to `#assign()`. Thus, the leader gets a global overview over the whole group, and thus can ensure that partitions are assigned in a co-located manner.

In the last step, the broker received the computed assignment from the leader, and broadcasts it to all consumers of the group. This will result in a call to `#onAssignment()` on each consumer.

This might also help:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Architecture
- http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I'll try to emulated the Kafka Streams behaviour.  In case that doesn't work, do you know if something that supports Python like Apache Spark would give the same topic-joining behaviour as Kafka Streams?

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of Spark -- but it's micro batching approach seems to make it hard to do proper stream processing to me.