# Join Kafka streams in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-python, faust

I need to work with Kafka streams in Python and I am analyzing the different libraries available. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688971/c-char-array-initialization-what-happens-if-there-are-less-characters-in-the-st) provided some good answers and it looks like the [Faust fork](https://faust-streaming.github.io/faust/) is the most complete Kafka library in Python.
However, I need to join different Kafka streams and I am not sure how to accomplish this, or if it is even supported.

I searched Faust's documentation and saw that [there are some definitions in place](https://faust-streaming.github.io/faust/search.html?q=join) for joins, but if I go to the [source code](https://faust-streaming.github.io/faust/_modules/faust/joins.html#Join), they are not implemented. So it looks like they are not supported, but maybe I am missing something or there is a different library that does support it.

I also found [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027286/join-multiple-kafka-topics-by-key), but it is from 2017 so a lot could have changed in the Python world.

Comment: fluvii is another python library for this

Comment: Fluvii looks interesting, it hadn't showed up in my search yet.